# Warning-Array subscript char

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have written this code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int height[26],ht[10];
    string str;
    for(int i=65;i<91;i++){
        cin>>height[i];
    }
    cin>>str;
    unsigned int length=str.length();
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<length;i++){
        ht[i]=height[str[i]];
    }
    int max=ht[0];
    for(unsigned int i=1;i<length;i++){
        if(max<ht[i]){
            max=ht[i];
        }
    }

    cout<<max;
}
```

1.I have stored in the height of each alphabet in an array height.
2.I have copied this array onto other array ht[],**ht[i]=height[str[i]];** which gives me a warning array subscript char.
3.The height of the alphabets is not greater than 7.

When I print the maximum value(max) i get a very large value(1038822517).
How can I rectify my code?

Comment: Your first `for` loop is trying to access an out-of-bounds index into `height`. `i` must be between 0 and 25, inclusive.

Comment: Debug your program with a one-letter string for starters. Step through one line at a time. Is the problem in the code that tallies the frequencies? Or is it in the code that finds the maximum?

Comment: @qxz I am accessing 26 locations.Why is it a problem?

Comment: Although you're accessing 26 elements, and there `height` size is 26, you're accessing the _wrong elements_. You're attempting to access `height[65]` and `height[66]`, whereas you can only access `height[0]` through `height[25]`.

Comment: @Tas why is this working then? for(int i=65;i<91;i++){
  cin>>height[i];
 }
 for(int i=65;i<91;i++){
   cout<<height[i];
  }

Comment: Are you running in Debug? Chances are the compiler allocated more room than necessary, and you're just overriding elements in `ht` and `str`

Comment: `ht[i]=height[str[i]];` not sure what you are doing with this piece of code

Comment: @Tas Just running normally in eclipse

Comment: @macroland consider string to be **abc** ht[0]=height[65],ht[1]=height[66],ht[2]=height[67].I am storing the values of height in ht

Answer (score 1):

As [@qxz pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253937/warning-array-subscript-char#comment69708532_41253937), you're accessing an out-of-bounds area of your array `height`:

```
int height[26];
for(int i=65;i<91;i++){
    cin>>height[i];
}
```

Here you declare an array `height` of 26 elements. These elements can be accessed from `0` to `25`, but you're attempting to access elements from `65` to `90`. This is undefined behaviour. Change your `for` loop:

```
int height[26];
const int startCharacter = 'A'; // use character literal instead of a number. 'A' will evaluate to 65
for(int i = startCharacter; i <= 'Z'; i++){
    cin>>height[i - startCharacter];
}
```

Instead of accessing element `65`, you'll correctly access `65 - 65 = 0` which is the first element in `height`. The next element will be `66 - 65 = 1` which is the second element.

Comment: my output is still the same

Comment: A better alternative is `startCharacter = 'A';`.  Character literals are always preferred over their ASCII decimal encodings.